# Should one say the extra shema on shabbos one would normally say during the week?

Tags: shabbat, tefilla, tefilin, shacharis-morning-prayer

Someone who puts on rabeinu tam at the least says shema as well as other parts of chumash that reference tefillin. Although obviously no tefillin on worn on shabbos should one recite these passages that would have been said during the week so as not to take away from the number of prayers said on shabbos verus a week day?

Comment: There are lots of weekday prayers not said on Shabbat (eg. the blessing beginning _Teka' beShofar_). Why should this be of concern?

Comment: No, in fact, Mesechtah Brochos states that the rabbis were concerned to "remove the burden of prayer" on Shabbos and replaced most of the Shmoneh Esrei with a single, longer blessing. The Talmud says that it is not forbidden to say the weekday blessings on Shabbos-- in fact, if you start saying one mistakenly, it seems that you are required to finish it-- but that weekday prayers are generally inappropriate for the Sabbath.

Comment: there are specific prayers not said on shabbos b/c we don't make requests on shabbos. the concern here (which aren't requests) is if another prayer is normally said during the week would it be a problem of taking away from tefilla?